# Subsonic 3.0 testing - what am I missing here?

Tags: testing, subsonic

EDIT: This issue is already submitted on Github. Changing the "Act" part to this will make the test pass

```
        var result = Adresse.All()
                .Where(x => x.AdresseX == txt1 && x.PostBy == txt2)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WTF()
    {
        //Arrange
        string txt1 = "Vingsted Skovvej 1";
        string txt2 = "7100 Vejle";

        var one = new Adresse { ID = 1, AdresseX = "Vejlevej 55", PostBy = "7300" };
        var two = new Adresse {ID = 2, AdresseX = txt1, PostBy = txt2 };
        Adresse.Setup(new List<Adresse> { one, two });

        //Act
        var result = Adresse.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AdresseX == txt1 && x.PostBy == txt2);            

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.ID);
    }
```

The following test fails me because I get the first object back (the one where ID equals 1)... Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Have you tried using Sql Profiler (if you're using SQL Server) to see what the SQL being produced is?

Comment: I'm using Subsonic 3.0 and the app.config connectionstring is pointed to "Test" so there's no DB activity going on

Comment: Have been searching through Stackoverflow - It seems that others have the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232405/subsonic-unit-testing-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is logged as an issue on [github](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues#issue/109), it would be worth you adding any info you can to it though.